# E-mail etiquette for addressing someone more senior than me who is providing support to me

Tags: email-etiquette

I find myself often in such a situation where I am on the receiving end of a technical support conversation with someone older and more senior than me. In my culture, I wouldn't normally address them by their name only, even if they are in a position to provide support to my company. However, it feels odd to start a mail by Mr/Mrs as it sounds way too abstracted -to me at least. Although I try to be quite polite and nice throughout the e-mail, I still feel awkward greeting people this way.

How would you greet people if you were in my position, or is this not an issue at all? Thank you for your time.

Comment: It really depends on your culture. In the US, it's common to use first names or even to omit the greeting at the beginning of the email once an email thread has been established. You are in the best position to find out what is most appropriate for your situation. Find someone at your level/age who is respected in the organization and ask them how they address others-- use that as a model for your email etiquette.

Comment: "It feels odd to start a mail by Mr/Mrs as it sounds way too abstracted" Do you mean: too formal? Or maybe you can explain what you mean by abstracted?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere mainly middle eastern.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie I meant inhumane, or not sincere enough.

Comment: *"I meant inhumane, or not sincere enough"* Ah, so it comes across as robotic/cold or not friendly enough? You want to sound respectful but still sound like a person.

Comment: @BSMP yes, exactly. Also, I failed to mention my contacts are generally outside of the middle east region, mainly from Europe or the US. This was actually the cause for my concern.

Comment: @GuarneerFPS, Then communicate with them the way they're used to in their culture. I can't speak for European work culture, it's a little bit different everywhere and it can also vary on the field you work in, but in my case in the US (on the West coast and in Tech), I don't like people using formal communication with me (especially once I've gotten to know them).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're responding to an email from them, you can address them in the same way they sign off their emails (usually first name only). If it's a first email or you're unsure, you could just use a 'Good morning' or 'Good afternoon' without adding a name at all.

I would say that most people do not attach much meaning to how they're addressed in an email. In fact, I usually only notice if it's jarring - which is usually when someone addresses me erroneously (eg as Mrs, Mr or Sir).

Answer (score 0):

**This answer is not from a middle-eastern perspective, just a very general answer.**

I don't know anything about what is suitable for your culture other than what you have said.

> In my culture, I wouldn't normally address them by their name only... Although I try to be quite polite and nice throughout the e-mail, I still feel awkward greeting people this way.

Feeling awkward is OK. Going against your culture, not so much.

If they include a salutation in their emails, that's usually a good hint for your to do the same. If you do include a salutation, it should be according to the your custom. If they don't include a salutation, it's probably fine to omit it.

> However, it feels odd to start a mail by Mr/Mrs as it sounds way too abstracted -to me at least.

I suspect some of this... oddness... is due to the fact we live in the instant messaging age. I would probably say that email is closer to letters than instant messaging, where letters almost always include a salutation.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I failed to mention that my contacts are often outside of the middle east region; mainly from Europe or the US.